# Error while running fastStructure: ImportError: No module named allelefreq

Tags: python

I'm trying to run faststructure software. Aftering installing numpy, scipy, cython, gsl1.16, when I try to run "python structure.py",it gives the following error:

```
$ python structure.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "structure.py", line 3, in <module>
    import fastStructure
  File "vars/admixprop.pxd", line 5, in init fastStructure
    cdef class AdmixProp:
  File "allelefreq.pxd", line 7, in init admixprop
ImportError: No module named allelefreq
```

Can anyone help me? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you followed all of the installation instructions on https://rajanil.github.io/fastStructure/ ? Also take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/structure-software/bdsmLwYtgdM which seems to address your issue.

Comment: what's the output of `pip freeze`?

Comment: @lagom  the output is following:  antlr==2.7.5rc1  ... xlwt==0.7.5

Comment: What's the Cython version?

Comment: @Jens I’ve followed all the instructions. distruct.py and chooseK.py are OK. If I change “import fastStructure” to “import structure”, structure.py will be ok. But the test/ runs with error: NameError:name ‘fastStructure’ is not defined. I don’t know how to do this.

Comment: @lagom cython version 0.29.2

Comment: @lagom it does work! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I remember some new version of cython have some issues(Forget the detail), but downgrade cython version maybe a solution:

Like follows:

```
pip uninstall cython
pip install cython==0.27.3
```

Then build again as document said and remember to add `-f` to force update, something like follows:

```
cd ~/proj/fastStructure/vars
python setup.py build_ext -f --inplace

cd ~/proj/fastStructure
python setup.py build_ext -f --inplace
```